# grails groovy list getAt(start..end) with Variables

Tags: list, groovy, range

How can I get listelements with variables:

```
var start = 5
var end = 10
myList.getAt(start..end)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here You go:

```
def list = [1,2,4]
def a = 1
def b = 2
assert list.getAt((a)..(b)) == [2, 4]
assert list[a..b] == [2, 4]
```

Comment: or simply `list[a..b]`.

Comment: Will add it as an assertion.